# Ad Block Plus Blocking jQuery Script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, adblock

I have a script that pulls data from my CMS and then allows a person to vote on a poll. The script works fine. However, I have Ad Block Plus Plugin installed in Firefox. When that is enabled to blocks the script from submitting the form correctly. It appears to submit correctly in the front end but is never registered in the back end.

Why does Ad Block Plus block my script that has nothing to do with ads?

The script is below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var Engine = {
        ui: {
            buildChart: function() {

                if ($("#pieChart").size() === 0) {
                    return;
                }

                var pieChartData = [],
                    totalVotes = 0,
                    $dataItems = $("ul.key li");

                // grab total votes
                $dataItems.each(function (index, item) {
                    totalVotes += parseInt($(item).data('votes'));
                });

                // iterate through items to draw pie chart
                // and populate % in dom
                $dataItems.each(function (index, item) {
                    var votes = parseInt($(item).data('votes')),
                        votePercentage = votes / totalVotes * 100,
                        roundedPrecentage = Math.round(votePercentage * 10) / 10;

                    $(this).find(".vote-percentage").text(roundedPrecentage);

                    pieChartData.push({
                        value: roundedPrecentage,
                        color: $(item).data('color')
                    });
                });

                var ctx = $("#pieChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
                var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(pieChartData, {});

            }, // buildChart

            pollSubmit: function() {

                if ($("#pollAnswers").size() === 0) {
                    return;
                }

                var $form = $("#pollAnswers"),
                    $radioOptions = $form.find("input[type='radio']"),
                    $existingDataWrapper = $(".web-app-item-data"),
                    $webAppItemName = $existingDataWrapper.data("item-name"),
                    $formButton = $form.find("button"),
                    bcField_1 = "CAT_Custom_1",
                    bcField_2 = "CAT_Custom_2",
                    bcField_3 = "CAT_Custom_3",
                    $formSubmitData = "";

                $radioOptions.on("change", function() {

                    $formButton.removeAttr("disabled"); // enable button

                    var chosenField = $(this).data("field"), // gather value
                        answer_1 = parseInt($existingDataWrapper.data("answer-1")),
                        answer_2 = parseInt($existingDataWrapper.data("answer-2")),
                        answer_3 = parseInt($existingDataWrapper.data("answer-3"));

                    if (chosenField == bcField_1) {
                        answer_1 = answer_1 + 1;
                        $formSubmitData = {
                            ItemName: $webAppItemName,
                            CAT_Custom_1: answer_1,
                            CAT_Custom_2: answer_2,
                            CAT_Custom_3: answer_3
                        };
                    }

                    if (chosenField == bcField_2) {
                        answer_2 = answer_2 + 1;
                        $formSubmitData = {
                            ItemName: $webAppItemName,
                            CAT_Custom_1: answer_1,
                            CAT_Custom_2: answer_2,
                            CAT_Custom_3: answer_3
                        };
                    }

                    if (chosenField == bcField_3) {
                        answer_3 = answer_3 + 1;
                        $formSubmitData = {
                            ItemName: $webAppItemName,
                            CAT_Custom_1: answer_1,
                            CAT_Custom_2: answer_2,
                            CAT_Custom_3: answer_3
                        };
                    }

                    prepForm($formSubmitData);

                });


                function prepForm(formSubmitData) {

                    $formButton.click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        logAnonUserIn("anon", "anon", formSubmitData); // log user in

                    }); // submit

                } // prepForm

                function logAnonUserIn(username, password, formSubmitData) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/ZoneProcess.aspx?ZoneID=-1&Username=' + username + '&Password=' + password,
                        async: true,
                        beforeSend: function () {},
                        success: function () {},
                        complete: function () {
                            fireForm(formSubmitData);
                        }
                    });
                } // logAnonUserIn

                function fireForm(formSubmitData) {
                    // submit the form

                    var url = "/CustomContentProcess.aspx?A=EditSave&CCID=13998&OID=3931634&OTYPE=35";

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: url,
                        data: formSubmitData,
                        async: true,
                        success: function () {},
                        error: function () {},
                        complete: function () {
                            window.location = "/";
                        }
                    });
                }

            } // pollSubmit

        } // end ui

    };

    Engine.ui.buildChart();
    Engine.ui.pollSubmit();

});
```

Comment: I have also saw that behavior with Chrome. It returns net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT, but I don't know why.

Comment: +1 for not spamming "var".      Note: I have encountered this kind of problem with adBlockPlus when getting images whose file path contain the folder /ad/, it may put you on a track...

Comment: Probably something in querystring/file name matches a rule in the adblocker file filter list.

Comment: @nicolallias - I have seen that as well. I cannot find anything with the word "ad" on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out easylist contains this filter:

```
.aspx?zoneid=
```

This is why my script is being blocked.

I was told I can try this exception filter:

```
@@||example.com/ZoneProcess.aspx?*$xmlhttprequest
```

I could also ask easylist to add an exception.

[Answer comes from Ad Block Plus Forums.](https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=23073)

Comment: Yea, well, adding local exceptions doesn't help the individual users.